# Change intl-tel-input field width in angular

Tags: angular, intl-tel-input

I have using the [Nebular ngx-admin template](https://www.akveo.com/ngx-admin/pages/dashboard?utm_campaign=ngx_admin%20-%20website%20-%20nebular%20landing%20-%20traffic&utm_source=nebular&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=nebular_docs_home_hero) in my angular application. Also using [ng2-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tel-input) for mobile number input.
I am having the below HTML code

```
<div class="form-control-group">
          <label class="label" for="input-mobile">Mobile<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
          <input nbInput type="text" id="input-mobile" class="input-mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" fullWidth fieldSize="large" formControlName="mobile" inputmode="numeric" digitOnly [status]="status(formcontrols.mobile)"
            ng2TelInput [ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'in'}">
</div>
```

but after building the Angular application. it looks like the below code. I found it by developer tools in the browser

[image]

**Issue:**

Unable to change the width of the input field like other fields shown in the above picture.

**Tried**

I have changed the width of the iti class *directly in the developer tools* like below

```
.iti {
width:100%;
}
```

It is working well. But I can't apply width property from styles file like below

in component.scss

```
.iti {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is worked finally for me. I have used the following,

in component.scss

```
:host ::ng-deep .iti {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Reason for this**

Style is not applied due to style encapsulation in angular. Refer to [this link](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) for more.

Answer (score 2):

It is worked for me.
I added the code below in component.css

```
.iti--allow-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The previous answers do not work in the new version..Unfortunately I can't delete!

Comment: This is the best option as using `width: 100%` on `.iti` affects how the mobile dropdown behaves.